# How to avoid loading multiple files into memory?

Tags: python, pandas

I load different CSV files as pandas Data Frames into memory, which may lead to OutOfMemory error. I load them all at once, because I should do joining operations.

Is there any way to avoid loading all files at once into memory?

```
myfiles= load_all_files(mypath)

myfiles.df1 = myfiles.df1\
    .query("IdType not in ['A','B','C']")\
    .drop(columns='IdType')\
    .groupby('IdGroup')\
    .agg('sum')\
    .join(myfiles.df2)\
    .groupby('IdV')\
    .agg('sum')

myfiles.d3 = myfiles.df3\
    .query("IdType not in [1,2,3]")\
    .drop(columns='IdType')\
    .groupby('IdGroup')\
    .agg('sum')\
    .join(myfiles.df4)\
    .groupby('IdV')\
    .agg('sum')

# other similar operations
```

Comment: check out dask : https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial

Comment: You can join upon load, e.g. pass read_csv(...) to join. Besides, *del* objects whenever you don't need them anymore.

Comment: @OlegO: Does "del" frees the memory?

Comment: If you don't have other aliases for this variable, yes (in most cases).